# HDMI-CEC pass through reciever?

Tags: hdmi, openelec

my setup is this:

- Samsung LCD TV
- Raspberry Pi model b rev 2
- Logitec Harmony One Remote
- Yamaha HTR-4065 AVR

and it have worked really well to controll openelec with the harmony remote (that was set to controll the TV). i recently bought the reciever and it continued to work great, but today the pi stopped recognizing the CEC-signals from the harmony remote. It does however recive the signals if i use the recievers remote. (but that's not a good solution for a bunch of reasons).

how can i make the raspberry pi recieve the cec signals from the tv through the reciever like it worked earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution myself, pretty logical when i think about it...

If i disable CEC on the AVR, the TV-CEC signals are going through fine. I guess the cable cant send CEC-signals for multiple machines simultaneously.

The strange thing is that i can't remember ever changing that setting on the AVR (pretty sure it's been on all the time) even when it worked earlier.

Hope this can help if anyone finds themselves in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. I have - sort of - the same setup here!

Well, I plugged th RPi into my TV (Samsung with CEC, I can control XBMC trough it). Set the TV to use an external source for the Audio and with an optical cable connected my Z-5500.

In my TV there's and option to turn CEC on/off and also when it is enabled there's a list of Devices it recognizes.

Try making sure your TV -> Pi commands are ok (test with another ROM). Then work your way there.

Hope I got something to offer, not needing a mouse/keyboard is great.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i actually tried this on to different SD-cards one with raspbmc and one with openelec, same result. found my solution myself lter as you can se above.